# How to get last message of every chat session in IOS using smack with openfire?

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, openfire, smack

I have implemented chat in my IOS application, its connecting and chatting successfuly, i am also getting all chat history of a user one to one chat, Now i want to implement the chat history screen where only chat sessions will be shown of one user with others if made.

1. Is there any way that openfire sends that list ?
2. Is there any way that i can get the last message of every conversation?

I tried to found a proper solution but no luck then tried below methods,

1. I tried some methods, but one will send all chat messages, and i need to process that list on my own in application and then use but thats a big loss of data.
2. The other way is to hit every user get their full chat history get its last message and display but that also not as effecient.
3. There's one more way to do that and its to make an array that keeps updating his attribute as user id, time and last message. Which will keep updates once the user updates its chat and then use that to populate all chats history screen.

Can any one please suggest if there's a better way to implement this ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The mentioned requirements are custom and not supported by Openfire. So you are left with some logic on client side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save Chat History of every user on Core Data and then display Last message of every user from Core Data.
If you are using "Robbiehanson" (https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) framework then it is already doing this.

Comment: Will you please tell me how to fetch chat history with particular user using XEP-0313